# Sub menu indicator that links to sub menu

Tags: customization, menus, sub-menu, mobile

I am trying to create a custom mobile menu for my wordpress site. I have looked around the net for an answer and found similar things or different ways that I can accomplish this but not in the way desired.

I would like to get the title of a menu item which has a sub menu attached to it and create a sub menu indicator to the right of the menu item. I am calling the menu by the wp_nav_menu function and the sub menu displays as of right now but I would like it to only display when the user clicks on the submenu link.
I have read that there is an $after parameter on the wp_nav_menu function but I do not know how to use it and have not found anything that helps. I have been looking for a way to do this for at least a week now.

along with this...the menu item should still point to the original page.

right now this is my code...

```
<nav class="mobile-nav" id="mobile-nav">
<?wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mobile-menu', 'container' => 'mobile-nav' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

and the website is http://www.texasdepos.com
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.